# Need Font Awesome 5 Support for SVG with JS in DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, svg, fonts, font-awesome, dhtmlx

We have many sites whose Internet Explorer will not show web fonts (they are locked down by group policies). So they cannot see any font awesome icons in our [DHTMLX](https://dhtmlx.com/) app. This is a major issue for us. We have been waiting for [Font Awesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/) to be released because we have verified that their new [SVG with JS approach](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js) works. FA5 is now released so we are trying to figure out how to incorporate it into DHTMLX.

This is what I've tried so far...

- I placed the new font awesome 5 file `fontawesome-all.js` into the `/dhtmlx/codebase/fonts/font_awesome/` folder.
- Then I updated the reference to it in the page: `<script defer src="/dhtmlx/codebase/fonts/font_awesome/fontawesome-all.js"></script>`

Now the new font awesome 5 icons appear but I see double (2) of each for some reason. Any ideas?  Thanks!

[image]

**UPDATE:** The bug appears to be in DHTMLX in the [dhtmlXMenu.addNewSibling() method](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxmenu_addnewsibling.html).  If I remove the disabled image property (imgDis) then I only see one font awesome icon, great, but if I make that menu item disabled then I don't see any image.  So it seems DHTMLX need to tweak their enabled/disabled functionality for FA5 icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem.
But I refused to set the property:

```
myToolbar.setIconset ("awesome");
```

I set the icon through the "text" property:

```
"text": "<i class = 'fas fa-plus'> </ i>"
```

and I define css for dhx_toolbar_btn, for example so:

```
.dhx_toolbar_btn {
     color: # 557BA6;
     font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

In this case, "disabled" works properly.

I hope this helps.